# Unity visual studio data folder not found error

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi we have a 4 player arcade shooting game which is PC based. We bought this game from China and it was working well. But 2 days ago we had to give team viewer access to China company due to some other issue. We gave the team viewer through usb mobile data. Ever since it keeps giving the error that data folder is not there and in the message box “there should be huntingzon_data folder next to the executable”.  I have not attached the specific error message as I don’t have the rights to do so.

Another thing I notice is the actual game size is 3.3 GB when ever we run the exe file the files from the data folder which contains the game files gets automatically deleted and the game folder size reduces to 84 gb

We have an expo in 3 days where we need to demo this game and I need to pack and send this game to another city in time for expo. The game seems to be in unity and visual studio. We don’t have the source files and we are not programmers or techies

Any help greatly appreciated. The Chinese company is on holiday for Chinese New Year so unable to help. They have sent the game files again but still we get the same error. I can provide team viewer access if required and also you can contact me on whatsap +919841081945

Comment: We  don’t have unity installed in the system and we don’t have a source file only have the EXE file

Comment: Did you test it on another PC? Why don't you have the rights to post an error message? If you only receive an exe file (+the missing folder) you probably have to ask for the missing folder again / reinstall the game. Anyway this question isn't really about Unity since as it sounds you are not actively using Unity but just start a custom software which isn't working correctly. => Only the support of that software can really help you

Comment: Hi to post an image we need a higher reputation. All the files are there. Exe and the folder. A peculiar thing we noticed is that the game size is 3.3 GB but whenever we run the exe it goes down to 84 mb. All the game files get deleted when the exe is run. We made all the game files read only after that the files aren’t deleted but the game crashes after launch. All firewalls etc is disabled. We also tried on another PC with new files ( since we had the rar ) but same thing happens. The Chinese are on new Year holiday so they will reply at a later date by then expo will be over.